# Strange behavior with SetTimeout and ScrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why I have to wrap the `scrollTop` function inside a `setTimeout`. I know what is happen with setTimeout behind the scene : put function in the Callback queue (providing from web API) and gonna be executed when all code in the call stack is done. But why in this case I have this behavior without `setTimeout` ?

Select `spain` and `luxembourg` (ctrl+click) for example, stay at the bottom of the `select` selector. Test with both buttons. Happen two differents behaviors.

**EDIT 1:** EDIT : Remove all `console.log`, still not working without `setTimeout`

**EDIT 2 :** After the first answer, I tried the code from @Murali Nepalli and still not working. You can see what it happen exactly (i'm on Google Chrome)

**EDIT 3 :** Only appear on Chrome, my version : `75.0.3770.142 (Build officiel) (64 bits) (cohort: Stable)`

[image: scrollTop not working]

```js
$(function() {

  $('form').on('resetwithtimeout', function(e) {

    var $select = $(e.currentTarget).find('select');

    $select.find('option')
      .filter(':selected').prop("selected", false).end()
      .filter(':first').prop("selected", true);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $select.scrollTop(0);
    }, 0);

  });

  $('form').on('resetwithouttimeout', function(e) {

    var $select = $(e.currentTarget).find('select');

    $select.find('option')
      .filter(':selected').prop("selected", false).end()
      .filter(':first').prop("selected", true);

    $select.scrollTop(0);
  });

  $('#button1').on('click', function(e) {
    $('form').trigger('resetwithtimeout');
  })

  $('#button2').on('click', function(e) {
    $('form').trigger('resetwithouttimeout');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form>
    <select name="country" id="country-select" multiple size="5">
      <option selected value="austria">Austria</option>
      <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
      <option value="bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="croatia">Croatia</option>
      <option value="republic">Republic of Cyprus</option>
      <option value="czech">Czech Republic</option>
      <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
      <option value="estonia">Estonia</option>
      <option value="finland">Finland</option>
      <option value="france">France</option>
      <option value="germany">Germany</option>
      <option value="greece">Greece</option>
      <option value="hungary">Hungary</option>
      <option value="ireland">Ireland</option>
      <option value="italy">Italy</option>
      <option value="latvia">Latvia</option>
      <option value="lithuania">Lithuania</option>
      <option value="luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
      <option value="malta">Malta</option>
      <option value="netherlands">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="poland">Poland</option>
      <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
      <option value="romania">Romania</option>
      <option value="slovakia">Slovakia</option>
      <option value="slovenia">Slovenia</option>
      <option value="spain">Spain</option>
      <option value="sweden">Sweden and the UK</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button1" type="button">Reset form with scroll inside setTimeout</button>
    <button id="button2" type="button">Reset form with scroll not inside a setTimeout</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, you don't need setTimeout to make it work. If you put the console.log in resetwithouttimeout, it will print "working" too.

Comment: I don't want to use `console.log()`, i removed them, and of course it will print "working" but NOT with the scrollTop behavior !

Comment: ???? I wasn't aware that `resetwithtimeout` is an Event.

Comment: @StackSlave: That's a custom event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Chrome bug.

For whatever reason, they try to call [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on the last user-selected <option> every time we programmatically change the selected property of one of the <option>s, as demonstrated in this snippet:

```js
var $select = $('select')
  .on('input', function() {
    console.log('try to scroll inside the select');
    current = 0;
    this.scrollTop = 0; // move to top
    startSelect();
    $select
      .find('.user-selected').removeClass('user-selected')
      .end().find(':selected').addClass('user-selected');
  })
var $options = $select.find('option');
var current = 0;

console.log('select any option');

// selects all the <option>s one by one
function startSelect() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $options.prop("selected", false)
      .get(current).selected = true;
    // call recursively
    if ((++current) < 26) startSelect();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.user-selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <select name="country" id="country-select" multiple size="5">
    <option value="austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="croatia">Croatia</option>
    <option value="republic">Republic of Cyprus</option>
    <option value="czech">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option value="estonia">Estonia</option>
    <option value="finland">Finland</option>
    <option value="france">France</option>
    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="greece">Greece</option>
    <option value="hungary">Hungary</option>
    <option value="ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="italy">Italy</option>
    <option value="latvia">Latvia</option>
    <option value="lithuania">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="malta">Malta</option>
    <option value="netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="poland">Poland</option>
    <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
    <option value="romania">Romania</option>
    <option value="slovakia">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="slovenia">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="sweden">Sweden and the UK</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And since they apparently call it with the `{ behavior: "auto" }` option, you can't even be sure that your `setTimeout(fn, 0)` will be enough to counter it.

But for what you are trying to do, maybe the [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method of the <form> element might suit, or even just a `<button type="reset">`. These are not affected by this weird behavior:

```js
var $form = $('form');
var $select = $form.find('select');
$form.on('reset', function() {
  $select.scrollTop(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <select name="country" id="country-select" multiple size="5">
    <option selected value="austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="croatia">Croatia</option>
    <option value="republic">Republic of Cyprus</option>
    <option value="czech">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option value="estonia">Estonia</option>
    <option value="finland">Finland</option>
    <option value="france">France</option>
    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="greece">Greece</option>
    <option value="hungary">Hungary</option>
    <option value="ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="italy">Italy</option>
    <option value="latvia">Latvia</option>
    <option value="lithuania">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="malta">Malta</option>
    <option value="netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="poland">Poland</option>
    <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
    <option value="romania">Romania</option>
    <option value="slovakia">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="slovenia">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="sweden">Sweden and the UK</option>
  </select>
  <button type="reset">Reset form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks dude for your explaination and dat good trick, I never seen before this `type`attribute on a `button` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the selection index of "select" element. That will reset the scroll position to top.  https://jsfiddle.net/hbL8tzma/

```
$('form').on('resetwithouttimeout', function(e) {
    var $select = $(e.currentTarget).find('select');
    $select[0].selectedIndex = 0;      
});
```

Comment: Mhhh, don't work for me, it's can't work like this we have to add `.end().end()` to go back at the root : `select`. I try on last version of Google Chrome i don't konw if you too.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the solution. Just change the selectionIndex that should take care of resetting scroll position. I verified on chrome Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)    https://jsfiddle.net/hbL8tzma/.

Comment: Good solution, but the explanation of the problem is a bit off.

Comment: @Kaiido: Edited explanation :)

Comment: Nope still off. Look at my answer for the real cause. It's not OP's code that is to be incriminated, it's Chrome behavior.